# CSS animation loader moving

Tags: html, css, css-animations

**Update:** It appears that a scrollbar is appearing for half a second, which pushes the animation to the left. Then when the scrollbar disappears, the animation shifts back into the middle. What is going on? How can I fix it?

I tried adding this line of code to my PHP file. It should be the very first thing that loads. But, the scrollbar still appears for half a second.

```
echo " <style> * {overflow: hidden;} </style> ";
```

---

I have a loading screen. I am using CSS to create the animation. During the loading, the animation works well but it doesn't stay perfectly in its spot. After about 2 seconds, the animation's location makes a very small change in position. How can I fix it so that the animation remains perfectly fixed in the center of the screen?

```css
#loading_screen {
  background: #add9e4;
  background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, circle cover, #f7fbfc 0%, #add9e4 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, color-stop(0%, #f7fbfc), color-stop(100%, #add9e4));
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, circle cover, #f7fbfc 0%, #add9e4 100%);
  background: -o-radial-gradient(center, circle cover, #f7fbfc 0%, #add9e4 100%);
  background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, circle cover, #f7fbfc 0%, #add9e4 100%);
  background: radial-gradient(center, circle cover, #f7fbfc 0%, #add9e4 100%);
  background-color: #f7fbfc;
}

.loader_animation {
  border: 16px solid lightgrey;
  border-top: 16px solid blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="loading_screen" style="overflow:hidden; position:fixed; top:0px; left:0px; bottom:0px; right:0px; width:100%; height:100%; border:none; margin:0; padding:0; z-index:999999;">
  <div style="display:flex; justify-content:center; align-items:center; width:100%; height:100%;">
    <div class="loader_animation"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have made this Jsfiddle, I do not see anything wrong ? https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Yep I dont see anything wrong either.

Comment: I've created a pen, also see nothing wrong. I'm going to guess it has something to do with the screen transition after the animation (maybe rendering elements or removing elements causes the bug) Here's the pen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EWrvdV

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: I tried it on Google Chrome with Windows 10, and also on Firefox with Ubuntu 14.04. I get the same unwanted affect on both.

Comment: @Leon you added the jsfiddle homepage url instead of the fiddle itself. Care to share? @ Lumo5 also Chrome with Windows 10, don't see anything strange from the Code Snippet result.

Comment: I figured out what is going wrong but I still don't know how to fix it. When the page is loading a scroll bar suddenly appears and then disappears. This pushes the animation over to the left by about 5px and then when the scrollbar disappears, the animation goes back to the center. How can I fix that?